# BeautifulSoup can't find specific table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

My goal is to parse through a webpage which has 5 possible customers on the page, and get their name from each CustomerTable. Since there is 1 CustomerTable per customer, my thought was to first get the table from within the soup, and then parse through the tables' contents to get the customer's name.

I am getting the html of the web page using Python's request package. When parsing the plain text of the response, I can find the table with the class="CustomerTable" attribute. However, when I do

```
response = session.get(customersPage)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
for table in soup.find_all('table'):
  print(table.get('class'))
```

the table with CustomerTable as the class name is not found. In fact, of the 52 tables that are in the response.text, this snippet prints 'None' only 4 times. Is there a better way to go about my overall goal? And what is causing the tables in this page to not be found? The CustomerTables would have been generated by javascript, so is it possible that this is what causing the table to not be found in the soup?

Sorry I am unable to post the full contents of the webpage, however I can try to give as much context as possible. The contents are through a paid service and bought by my company.

Comment: Sorry if this seems too basic, but have you tried printing the contents being input to BeautifulSoup? if the tables are there, maybe there is a bug in the code..if not the scraping mechanism will have to be looked at.

Comment: @SohamA Yea, the response.text has the CustomerTable 1 time. I'm guessing the table is only in there once, and the contents are filled out after the response.text is created. That's why I have been thinking it has to do with the javascript being run after python-requests get the contents.

Comment: The tables are  generated using javascript so won't be available when you get the html, can you share the url?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham The actual url requires you have access to the paid service but it's on isell.onesource.com  What's the best way to go about getting the contents after the JS is run?

Comment: without seeing the html I could not really help, you could use selenium and phantomjs for headless browsing  which will work for javascript. I have used it before successfully.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That solved my question. Want to write a quick explanation as an answer and I'll mark it?

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: OS X 10.9.5. I think I'm going with selenium to take care of this.

Comment: install phantomjs using the instructions from here http://phantomjs.org/build.html it will be a lot more efficient than using an actual browser

Comment: need to see the html you are scraping.